# When I am adding button element inside the li element it is adding a br element on it's own

Tags: javascript, dom

So at first I was using inner to add the button inside the list but adding an eventlistener to it was causing unpredictable behavior where it was working only some of the time. SO I read something online and they were basically saying that doing document.createELement was a better way to do it as it actually adds the element in the dom and it is more robust I think.

after implementing it now the remove button is working great but the only issue is that it is adding a br element on it's own for some reason.

this is my code for adding changing the list:

```
list.innerHTML = ""
        for(let i=0; i<folder.definitions.length; i++){
            let id = `${folder.name}-${i}`
            let listElem = document.createElement("li")
            listElem.innerText = folder.definitions[i]
            let btn = createButtonHTML("-", id)
            listElem.appendChild(btn)
            list.appendChild(listElem)
            addingTheRemoveDefEvent(folder.name, id)
        }
```

and this is the elements as they were showing in the dev tools on my browser:

```
<ul>     
    <li>         
        ::marker         
        bar         
        <br>         
        <button id="foo">ting<button>     
    <li> 
<ul>
```

so I was just trying to have no br I never wanted to add br it is unexpected behavior and I would like to remove it

Comment: The example code doesn't create `br` element. Maybe it's `createButtonHTML` function adding the line-break?

Comment: umm the html I put is rendered by the browser but basically I was trying to show that inside my list element there is some text and a button and for some reason br is added in that innerhtml

Comment: The functions `createButtonHTML()` and `addingTheRemoveDefEvent()` need to be posted. Is `folder` an Object (ex. `const folder = {...}`)?

Comment: Have a look to folder.definitions[i],

Comment: A quick fix would be `document.querySelectorAll("li br").forEach(n => n.remove());` after the list is completed., but it's kind of messy tbh.

Comment: Ok I actually found it thank you all for the help but I actually found that the text file I was using to test the fileUpload function had an extra new line character. And the code itself was working fine so thank you so much I am going to set this as solved. And I know that I need to post these things I just hadn't gotten around to it but thank you for letting me know. I appreciate it!!